# ASP.net Site Stalling

Tags: asp.net

I made a small edit to the master file of an asp.net site. (Add some html code)

After I made the edit the site would no longer load. As a result, I went and removed my edit, and the site still wouldn't load.

It will not load any page, it just keeps loading but provides no output.

How do I debug, and/or fix this problem?

Comment: Hate to have to mention it but a restart of IIS would be a good place to start.

Comment: What do you see in Event Viewer?